# UIPopoverController setting frame size

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating a popover in this way:

```
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:browser];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(44, 400, 600, 800) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

for some strange reason whatever CGRectMake size I put, the result is the same, the popover takes all the hight of my view and half of the width. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have to set [contentSizeForViewInPopover](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/contentSizeForViewInPopover) property for your content view controller before presenting the popover.

Comment: ok, this works popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(400.0, 500.0);

Comment: but still, it seems that if I put any size I still have that problem. what shall I put instead of CGRectMake?

Comment: The CGRect which is passed to the `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` does not affect the size of the popover at all. It is needed to determine the position of the popover and the arrow direction. Apple's documentation states the following about this parameter: "The rectangle in view at which to anchor the popover window." So to set the size of the popover you have to use either the `popoverContentSize` of `UIPopoverController` or `contentSizeForViewInPopover` of your content `UIViewController`.